# Keep container open for first click of each nav item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I'm trying to figure out how I can do this -- I need to keep one container open through a click of a sibling list item, but then close it on the second click. The issue is going back to another link and having a handler left on it.

The concept would be to have:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item Four</a></li>
 </ul>
<div id="nav-content">
    <!-- Content changed with Ajax -->
</div>
```

Using this, I'm interchanging the content with ajax, so a click returns it into my "nav-content" div. When I click on one item, I want the content div to open, and then remain open when the next nav item link is clicked, but closed when it's clicked a second time.

Tried using unbind but I don't think that's appropriate, and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not posting relevant code in question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

- giving the `li` a class when you click it
- removing that class from all other `li`s
- then checking for that class before you hide or show your div

Essentially using a class to keep up with which `li` was clicked last

```js
$('#nav li').click(function(){
    
    // remove the `active` cass form all `li`s in `#nav` 
    // except the one that was clicked
    $('#nav li').not(this).each(function(){
          $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    // check if clicked element has `active` class
    // if so it was just clicked for second time, close the div
    if( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $('#nav-content').hide();
    }
    else{
      // if not it was clicked for the first time
      // show the div and make the clicked element `active`
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('#nav-content').show();
    }
    
  
});
```

```css
#nav-content{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item Four</a></li>
 </ul>
<div id="nav-content">
    <!-- Content changed with Ajax -->
  Here is some content
</div>
```