# How to track if each clicked item has been clicked before (or is its first click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue of getting the first click per link clicked, I have tried with one click event `.one()` but since I'm preventing the default it cause a redirection. I want to get add something if item clicked is equal to 1 and remove if clicked more than one time per a link.

```js
// $('.menu>li>a').one('click', function(e){}); 
let clickCount = 0;

$('.menu>li>a').on('click', function(e) {
  clickCount++;
  let $this = $(this);
  if (clickCount == 1) {
    //show loader
    $('.loader').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.loader').hide();
    }, 5000);
    $this.next('.dropdown').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $this.next('.dropdown').addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">item1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `preventDefault`? Why do you need to prevent the default behavior if you want the first click to succeed.

Comment: I used preventDefault because I just want to prevent anchor redirect during click event.

Comment: You might want to look at using a button for that. Try replacing the anchor with a button and remove the `preventDefault` and see if it comes any closer to solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [jQuery's data storage](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to know if a link has been clicked before. This would allow you to track each link individually:

```js
// $('.menu>li>a').one('click', function(e){}); 

$('.menu>li>a').on('click', function(e) {
  let $this = $(this);
  const firstClick = !$this.data('clickedBefore');
  if (firstClick) {
    $this.data('clickedBefore', true)
    //show loader
    $('.loader').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.loader').hide();
    }, 5000);
    $this.next('.dropdown').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $this.next('.dropdown').addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">item1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Update:

> is there another alternative without using data('clickedBefore', true) and adding class to link to achieve the same result?

Yes. Generally speaking, if all you need is just some control properties, using `data` is cleaner than adding classes. But if you intend to style the element or if your project already uses classes for control elsewhere (so keeping consistency would matter), it could make sense to use them instead:

```js
// $('.menu>li>a').one('click', function(e){}); 

$('.menu>li>a').on('click', function(e) {
  let $this = $(this);
  const firstClick = !$this.hasClass('clicked-before');
  if (firstClick) {
    $this.addClass('clicked-before');
    //show loader
    $('.loader').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.loader').hide();
    }, 5000);
    $this.next('.dropdown').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $this.next('.dropdown').addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">item1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. it works as I expect, but is there another alternative without using data('clickedBefore', true) and adding class to link to achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes. I'll add it to the answer. Just a sec

Comment: Thank you again. I would like to see it @acdcjunior

Comment: Just added. See the comment there as well. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can just add two event listeners for both use cases. One for you to disable the default behavior and one for the click you would like to capture.

```js
let clickCount = 0;

$('.menu > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('checking click for things');
  clickCount++;
  let $this = $(this);
  if (clickCount === 1) {
    console.log('Only the first click will show the loader');
    $('.loader').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.loader').hide();
    }, 5000);
    $this.next('.dropdown').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $this.next('.dropdown').addClass('active');
  }
});

$('.menu > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('All clicks will prevent default');
});
```

```css
.loader {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">item1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">content1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="loader">Loader</div>
```

Comment: I did not chose a .one click event because  I want to get first click and other click. if(firstclick){}else{}.

Comment: Well then change it to `on`

Comment: Alright ... you're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: All I want is something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891332/keep-container-open-for-first-click-of-each-nav-item

Comment: And why is their solution not working for you?

Comment: But I f same link clicked for first time then it will show a loader, but if it clicked for the second time and so on it will hide a loader.

Comment: I didn;t test since it need to add active class to a link. I wonder if it can be done without injecting active class